# Dockerfile - using ARG in ENTRYPOINT not working

Tags: spring-boot, dockerfile

I've simple SpringBoot application. And here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:18-jdk
LABEL version="1.0"

ARG PROJECT_NAME="test"
ARG PROJECT_VERSION="0.0.1"
ARG JAR_FILE="${PROJECT_NAME}-${PROJECT_VERSION}.jar"
ARG APP_HOME=/opt/deployment
ARG PROJECT_HOME=${APP_HOME}/${PROJECT_NAME}

COPY target/${JAR_FILE} ${PROJECT_HOME}/${JAR_FILE}

# Change working directory
WORKDIR ${PROJECT_HOME}


# Entrypoint
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", ${JAR_FILE}]
```

When I run this I'm getting following error:

```
/bin/sh: [java,: command not found
```

But when I give direct jar file(todo-0.0.1.jar) instead of ${JAR_FILE} in ENTRYPOINT, it's working. How can I use the variable in ENTRYPOINT?

Plese hlep

Answer (score 1):

"Unlike the shell form, the exec form does not invoke a command shell. This means that normal shell processing does not happen. For example, RUN [ "echo", "$HOME" ] will not do variable substitution on $HOME. If you want shell processing then either use the shell form or execute a shell directly, for example: RUN [ "sh", "-c", "echo $HOME" ]. When using the exec form and executing a shell directly, as in the case for the shell form, it is the shell that is doing the environment variable expansion, not docker."

source = https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

so i think you need something like this.

[ "sh", "-c", "java -jar $JAR_FILE" ]